# Vagrant remote box with libvirt issue

Tags: ssh, vagrant, ansible, libvirt

I am trying to make vagrant work with the following setup

- Two machines - One controller and one host
- Installed vagrant + vagrant-nodemaster plugin in controller (1.5.4 vagrant)
- Installed vagrant + vagrant-node + vagrant-libvirt in host machine

After installation I started nodeserver in host machine in an unused port. 
With the following configuration pushed from controller to host (using vagrant remote config upload )

```
config.vm.define :vm3 do |vm3|
    vm3.vm.network :private_network,
        :ip => "192.168.170.57",    
        :libvirt__network_name => "vagrantnw",  
        :libvirt__dhcp_enabled => false
end

config.vm.provider :libvirt do |libvirt|
    libvirt.driver = "qemu"
    # leave out host to connect directly with qemu:///system
    #libvirt.host = "localhost"
    libvirt.connect_via_ssh = false   # aeso needed
    libvirt.username = "root"
    libvirt.storage_pool_name = "default"
end

config.ssh.username = 'vagrant'
config.ssh.password = 'vagrant'
config.ssh.insert_key = 'true'
config.ssh.private_key_path = '/home/kk/ssh_privkey'
```

I am expecting that with the above configuration libvirt will create a vm with ip address as 192.168.170.57 with a valid nfs which can be mapped to host. Now, following are the issues I am facing

- VM is always created in 192.168.121.xx network with a dynamic ip address assigned in the same subnet. I am not able to create vm in the specific network which I want.
- I would like to remotely ssh into the vm using command 'vagrant remote ssh '. Or from a different host I would like to connect to the VM created above.
- I would like to ftp a file to the guest once remote ssh is working fine. I believe we can do this using ansible . But wanted to check if a quick and dirty way to do it through vagrant .

Thanks

Comment: Why do you need libvirt at all?

Comment: Add libvirt because the VM is optimized for libvirt. This is typical NFV - VNF scenario

Comment: Sounds interesting. Will need to read about that ...

Answer (score 2):

You can change the management network by adding the following lines in the provider definition:

```
   config.vm.provider :libvirt do |libvirt|
      ...
      libvirt.management_network_name = "vagrant-libvirt"
      libvirt.management_network_address = "10.75.250.0/25"
    end
```